# Unable to connect mysql after docker mysql created

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I setup my docker mysql and phpadmin via

```
    version: '3.2'

    services:
       mysqllocal:
          image: mysql:8.0
          container_name: container_mysqllocal
          restart: always
          ports:
           - '6603:3306'
          environment:
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: pass1234
            MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%'

       phpmyadmin:
          depends_on:
           - mysqllocal
          image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin
          container_name: container_phpmyadmin
          restart: always
          ports:
           - '8080:80'
          environment:
            PMA_HOST: mysqllocal
            UPLOAD_LIMIT: 3000000000
```

docker inspect container_mysqllocal and got '172.30.0.2'. However when I tried to connect mysql via SequelPro. It gives Connection Failed error. How do I connect mysql to my SequelPro / mysql workbench app, is there any configuration I've missed?

Below is the screenshot of my SequelPro connection:
[image]

Comment: Can you share how you are connecting to mysql in SequelPro?

Comment: @Subbu, I added the screenshot of the SequelPro connection setting

Comment: The `docker inspect` IP address doesn't work in many common environments (that looks like a MacOS dialog, and you can't use those addresses on MacOS); I wouldn't try to look it up.  You should be able to connect to the first `ports:` number (3306) on `localhost` if you're running the tool outside Docker on the same host as the container.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to access mysql from your local machine with the port defined, in your config is 6603

Comment: Hi Sulaiman Al-farisi, I did tried with the command 
docker exec -t -i container_mysqllocal /bin/bash -c "mysql -uroot -ppass1234" and did a sql command create schema test123. It does work and my phpmyadmin side able to see that I've added the schema database

Comment: okay, have you accessed it using "locahost" in sequelPro

Comment: tried both localhost and 127.0.0.1 on the host, connection fail as well